# Losing Value of Variable - C

Tags: c, ncurses

- Compiler:gcc 4.5.2
- Terminal:Xterm
- OS:Linux(x86)
- Ncurses 5.9

I am programming a text editor that uses ncurses to graphicaly represent an array `key_strokes[]`. It is one dimensional so I use the macro `INDEX(y*maxx+x)` to point to the current position in `key_strokes` (`key_strokes[INDEX]`). `y` and `x` are the current coordinates in the terminal returned by the function `getyx(stdscr, y, x)` and `maxx` is the max amount of cols that can be in each row returned by the function `getmaxyx(stdscr, maxy, maxx)`. The program works great until I press backspace, for some reason the value of `maxx` is set to zero after it reaches the switch below. This of course throws off `INDEX` limiting it to only the first "row" of the array.

The user's key strokes are captured as `int key_strokes`. I use a switch case to check and see if it is an arrowkey, backspace, F12, etc. `INDEX` and `maxx` are defined as,

```
#define INDEX (y*maxx+x)
unsigned int maxx = 0;
```

Note I am also using `cbreak(); noecho(); keypad(stdscr, TRUE);`.

```
case KEY_BACKSPACE:
if (INDEX >= 0)
{
   for(i = INDEX; key_strokes[i] != '\0'; i++) {
   key_strokes[i] = key_strokes[i+1];
   }

   if (total_count > 0) {
   total_count--;
   }

   delch();
   if (x == 0) {
   move(y-1, maxx-1);
   }
   else {
   move(y, x-1);
   } refresh();
}
break;
```

Comment: Do you have a `break` after the `case`? Are you sure `y*maxx+x` is always in the bounds of the array?

Comment: How big is the array `key_strokes`?  Are the variables `x`, `y`, and `maxx` function scope or global scope?  Have you printed key variables and values (`x`, `y`, `maxx`, `INDEX`, `total_count`) at appropriate points.  You may need to do that to a log file to avoid messing up the screen display.

Comment: Carnegie Yes I do have a break after the switch I just forgot to put it in the example I will add it now. And yes INDEX is always within the bounds of the array because the size of the array is maxy*maxx+1. @Leffler all variables are automatic and declared in the main() function. And I have a logging system in place. maxx equals 80 at the start of the program and its value stays constant until it reaches the backspace case at which it changes to 0.

Comment: I was not able to included this in my last comment because I ran out of characters. I tried declaring maxx as a constant and setting its value equal to x which was returned by getmaxyx(stdscr, y, x) by declaring maxx as const unsigned int maxx = x;. I also did the same for maxy and for some reason maxx stayed at 80 but maxy was set to 0 instead.

Comment: You might need to check the return value of initscr(). MAN_PAGES: " initscr  is  normally the first curses routine to call when initializing a program..... The initscr code determines the terminal type and initializes all curses data structures."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* that `key_strokes[]` is null terminated?

'cause if it isn't, the `for` loop will copy everything in memory to the previous cell, until it reaches 0. And if `maxx` or `maxy` are right before a 0 value, they will be set to 0.

Imagine the following layout:

```
| key_strokes[0] | key_strokes[...] |   key_strokes[n] | maxy | maxx | some_other_var |
|            'v' |              'i' | non-null garbage |   23 |   80 |           '\0' |
```

After pressing backsapce after 'i', it will be:

```
| key_strokes[0] | key_strokes[...] |   key_strokes[n] | maxy | maxx | some_other_var |
|            'v' | non-null garbage |               23 |   80 | '\0' |           '\0' |
```

That could also explain why it's `maxy` which is set to 0 when `maxx` is declared const (GCC doesn't store the `const`s at at the same place in memory).

To ensure that `key_strokes[]` is null-terminated, I'd suggest you to add this into your init section:

```
memset(key_strokes, 0, sizeof(char) * size_of_key_strokes_array);
```

Comment: Thanks very much you are correct I forgot about the terminating NULL character.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the type of x and y (ie. signed or unsigned), but it seems interesting that you calculate (y times an unsigned integer and add x). What may be the type of this expression? Probably it depends on the type of y. Is it reasonable to check if it's greater than or equal zero in the condition? (Unsigned values are always gte zero...)

Comment: The problem here is that variables lose their value. I assume that John did an ok job with the logging, and that the error happens in the code he pasted. `move` is a ncurses function, so it seems very improbable that a ncurses function modifies a variable of which it gets a _copy_. `total_count` can't be related either, since it's only a variable. But `key_strokes` is a pointer. It's the only possibility I see here.

Comment: @sportember If you have a linear one dimensional array that has no special characters like newlines. Then you can represent its index using x and y coordinates if you know the max number of x coordinates allowed in one row(y). Of course newlines will throw this off because a new line character is only one character but in reality it will take up 1 to maxx-1 characters because a newline will cause the cursor to move to (0, y+1).